# Separate lists/marks in bibliography possible?

Tags: bibliographies

I have my references.bib file ready (my main document class is article)

Some of my references are web pages (`@misc`) and most are scientific papers (`@article`). If I want the articles to be tagged [1], [2]... etc and the misc to be tagged [i], [ii]... etc, how would I go about doing that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}   
\cite{NSF_1}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you using `biblatex` as your tags suggest? Or do you use `natbib` or another bibliography package?

Comment: Yes, I am using biblatex (that's the built in one, right? I'm pretty new to TeX)

Comment: No `biblatex` is a package you need to load explicitly. The built-in solution is `thebibliography`? Can you show an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) of how you create your bibliography at the moment? You might want to read an introduction to bibliographies in TeX: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management

Comment: https://pastebin.com/eZjrXbyZ

Comment: OK, you are not using `biblatex`. You are using BibTeX. You could switch to `biblatex` to use my answer below (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864 and linked questions for help). If you insist on an answer that works with BibTeX and `unsrt` you might want to add that to your question.

Comment: Yes, after you posted your answer (thanks), I checked my GUI (I'm using texstudio) and it's calling biblatex by default. I changed it to biber to function with your posted answer. Biblatex seems to have its own version of unsrt so that's fine.

Comment: Well, `numeric` is a style similar to `unsrt`. You might want to add `sorting=none` to have a sorting similar to `unsrt`. If you need a style even closer to `unsrt` use `biblatex-trad`'s `style=trad-unsrt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fairly easy with [`biblatex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) ([biblatex in a nutshell (for beginners)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864)). In the MWE we filter `@online` entries and give them Roman numerals. All other entries get Arabic numbers. `resetnumbers` makes sure that the numbering of the `@online` entries starts with 'i' again and does not continue where the previous list left off (i.e. with 'iv'). `defernumbers` is needed when using `resetnumbers`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\ifentrytype{online}{\Rn{#1}}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\cite{markey,sigfridsson,wassenberg,baez/online,ctan,worman,nussbaum}
\printbibliography[nottype=online]
\printbibliography[title={Online Sources}, type=online, resetnumbers]
\end{document}
```

[image]